# How to send data already present in Model object from View to Controller in Spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, view, controller, thymeleaf

I have a Spring boot + Thymeleaf doubt. Let's say I have a controller with two handler methods like-

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
 
    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String test(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "This is just a message");
        return "test";
    }
 
    @GetMapping("/submit")
    public String submit() {
        //how to access model.getAttribute("message") here?
        return "submit";
    }
 
}
```

Now in test(), I am putting a key "message" in Model object and then returning test.html. Now, in test.html I can use ${message} however I want. Now in test.html, on click of a button I am redirecting to "/submit", but I also want the "message" key to be passed to "/submit" in Model object, so that I can use the same key in submit() too. How to achieve that?

test() ("message" key put in Model object ) -> test.html -> submit() (How to access model.getAttribute("message") here in submit() ?)

Comment: Can you explain a bit _why_ you want to do this? What is the underlying problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Let's say I submit a form and the data goes to test() and I put the data in Model object to be used in test.html. Now in test.html, I have a link say "Update data" on click of which, I will be redirected to submit() which will need the original data we filled, that was in Model object. So how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking does not make much sense in terms of what you actually want to do. You should think of `Model` as something that only lives to populate your Thymeleaf template with data during the rendering of the HTML page.

What you normally do is store the data either in an in-memory service or repository, or connect to any kind of database that can keep that data.

When you want to edit the data, you will usually have some kind of identifier that points to the data where you have stored it. With a relational database, this would be the primary key.

Say I have a `users` table with a `long` as primary key. To edit a user, you would typically have a controller method like this:

```
@GetMapping("/users/{id}")
public String editUser(@PathVariable("id") long id,
                       Model model) {
  User user = service.getUser(id);
  
  model.addAttribute("formData", FormData.fromUser(user));

  return "users/edit";
}
```

Where `users/edit.html` page would have a form to display the data to edit.

The form would do a POST to send the updated data back to the controller using a `@PostMapping` method, which would use the service to store the updated data.

If you want to read more about how to use forms with Thymeleaf, you can look at [Form handling with Thymeleaf](https://www.wimdeblauwe.com/blog/2021/05/23/form-handling-with-thymeleaf/)